# Show that ||T(M)|| $ \le$ ||M|| for all M

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the last part of a very long question.

$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\hspace{3pc} \text{and} \hspace{3pc} T(M) = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}a +id&b+ic\\c-ib&d-ia\end{pmatrix}
$$

More info about the question:

It has inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$ with respect to Frobenius inner product.

Now I have been trying to use $A^*A$, then determine eigenvalues method to determine the norm. But it produces a ridiculous string of values. I'm thinking I'm going about this problem in the wrong way.

Are there any other more efficient methods to determine the norm?

I have also inserted various values into M and the statement does appear to hold. But how to prove it for all values? Induction?

Comment: Do you know how to make fractions with "\frac" and "\dfrac"?  " \$ \frac{a}{b} \$" renders to $\frac{a}{b}$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is far simpler than I was making the problem.

Take Frobenius inner product of (||T(M)||)^2

Then do the same for M.

Simple to solve from there.